# Replace Integrate with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, replacement, hold

I have a symbolic integral with a pretty complex expression. I need it in symbolic form because I want to compute its derivative.

```
pdf:=PDF[NormalDistribution[0, {sigma1+sigma2}]]
f[delta_, c_] := Integrate[pdf[z], {z, delta + c, \[Infinity]}

num = Integrate[
   x*f[delta[t, {x, y}], c], {x, 0, w}, {y, 0, h}, {t, 0, tt}];
den = Integrate[
   f[delta[t, {x, y}], c], {x, 0, w}, {y, 0, h}, {t, 0, tt}];

Ds = D[num/den, {c, #} // FullSimplify]& /@ {1,2};
```

Now up to this point everything works fine, I get a list of my first and second derivative w.r.t `c`.

I now want to compute the *numerical* integral of `Ds[[1]]` evaluated, of course, at some numerical values for the limits and for some particular `delta[t, {x, y}]`.

Thus, I define

```
xi[t_]:={x0, y0}+rtraj*{Cos[Omega*t], Sin[Omega*t]}
intensity[t_, eta_]:= 1 - HeavisideTheta[r^2 - Norm[eta-xi[t]]]

rulesSignal = {delta-> intensity, x0-> 0, y0-> 0, omega-> 1, rtraj-> 1, r-> 0.25};
rulesIntegrals[c0_] := {tt-> 1, sigma1-> 0.1, sigma2-> 0.1, h-> 5, w-> 5, c-> c0};
allRules[c0_]:=Join[rulesSignal, rulesIntegrals[c0]];
```

Then, if I try

```
(Ds[[1]]/.Integrate -> NIntegrate)/.allRules[0.1]
```

whereas

```
(Ds[[1]] /. allRules[0.1]) /. Integrate -> NIntegrate
```

just does not ever return (ever as in a very long time), which I believe makes sense, as `intensity` is a not-nice-looking function and thus I expect that integral to take a very long time.

Is there a way to just trigger a numerical integration within this setting? I feel like it should be possible with some `Hold`ing black magic but, being pretty new to the Wolfram Mathematica world I cannot really figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please check your coding, especially the definition of `pdf[z_]:=...` (argument z doesn't appear on the righthand side)

Comment: I get syntax errors, and in trying to fix them, I get more.  I think you need to correct the code. (It's best if you check the code you posted, since apparently some error crept in while copying it from your notebook.)  We'll need to have a definition for the function `delta[]` in order to try out ideas.

Comment: Since you want numerical values anyway, there is no need to get the integral in symbolic form in order to compute its derivative. The usual difference quotient is an excellent approximation to the derivative if $\Delta$ is small enough.

Comment: I definitely see errors coming from my attempt of cleaning up the results of copy pasting. I will edit the code as soon as I get to the office. As for the delta function I am trying to substitute ot with another function defined above ( `intensity` ; third row of second code snippet). Thanks.